# google docs clear formatting and move cursor after a script is run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

So , I am trying to insert date and time in google docs and using the following google apps script to do that. I found this script in this site and edited a little bit. It's does the job. But my problem is, after the script is run the cursor stays at the same place, I want it to go the start of the next new line. Also the formatting to the page is stuck to the specified in the script, I want it to change like changing the font and size, reset bold etc. How do I do that?

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Utilities')
      .addItem('Insert Date', 'insertAtCursor')
      .addToUi();
}


function insertAtCursor() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", " MMMMM,dd \nhh:mm a \n"); 
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(true).setItalic(true).setForegroundColor("#A32929");
      element.setFontSize(16).setFontFamily('Cambria'); 
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your cursor to go the next line then somewhere in your code you have to assign a new position to the cursor. You do this with .setCursor(Position). Read more on that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer)).

The reason your formatting does not change is that can only run one formatting execution per line.

```
function insertAtCursor() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", " MMMMM,dd \nhh:mm a \n"); 
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(true);
      element.setItalic(true);
      element.setForegroundColor("#A32929");
      element.setFontSize(16);
      element.setFontFamily('Cambria'); 
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');

  }
var position =  doc.newPosition('your new position');
doc.setCursor(position);

}
```

Hope this helps.